# how to create a count variable that counts based on the value of a binary variable in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, repeat, longitudinal

code to create df: I have the repeat data that looks like the table below.

```
df <- structure(list(patid = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", 
                         "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"), observation_date = c("07/07/2016", 
                                                                        "07/08/2016", "07/11/2016", "07/07/2019", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                        "07/05/2015", "07/06/2015", "16/06/2015", "07/05/2015", "02/12/2016", 
                                                                        "18/12/2016", "15/01/2017"),
                      registration = c("0","0","1","1","0","1","0","0","0","0","1","1","1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                          -13L))
```

| patid | observation_date | registration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 07/07/2016 | 0 |
| 1 | 07/08/2016 | 0 |
| 1 | 07/11/2016 | 1 |
| 1 | 07/07/2019 | 1 |
| 2 | 07/05/2015 | 0 |
| 2 | 02/12/2016 | 1 |
| 3 | 07/05/2015 | 0 |
| 3 | 07/06/2015 | 0 |
| 3 | 16/06/2015 | 0 |
| 4 | 07/05/2015 | 0 |
| 4 | 02/12/2016 | 1 |
| 4 | 18/12/2016 | 1 |
| 4 | 15/01/2017 | 1 |

I would like to summarize data in this way: I want two rows only for each patid, one row will have a count of the observation_date when value of registration=0 and one row will have a count of the observation_date when value of registration=1. This is the code I tried but it is only giving a count of all observation_date per patid

```
cons_sum <- df%>%
         group_by(patid) %>%
         arrange(observation_date)%>%
         tally()
```

The final table should look like this:

| patid | registration | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 |

Comment: What is a "count of the observation_date when value of registration=0"? The difference in days?

Comment: No only a simple count of the observation (so the actual date is not important) I edited the question with the table I would like to create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count`. To make every possible value appear in the final table, you should convert your registration column to a factor:

```r
df %>% 
  count(patid, registration = factor(registration), .drop = FALSE)
```

output

```r
  patid registration n
1     1            0 2
2     1            1 2
3     2            0 1
4     2            1 1
5     3            0 3
6     3            1 0
7     4            0 1
8     4            1 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `base R`

```
as.data.frame(table(df[c('patid', 'registration')]))
  patid registration Freq
1     1            0    2
2     2            0    1
3     3            0    3
4     4            0    1
5     1            1    2
6     2            1    1
7     3            1    0
8     4            1    3
```